# R sanitize pattern for regular expression detection

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a list of patterns and a dataframe with a string column called `test`. On each pattern I want to test if the pattern is detected in the `test` column or not. I do that in a loop (using `map` for example).

My issue is that some of the patterns contain special characters, and some do not. And some of the strings in `test` also contain special characters. Examples of special characters are: "#" "/" "." "*" etc....

The detection I am trying to do is straightforward. Does the pattern string exist anywhere in each value the `test` column (beginning, middle or end).

How do I "santinize" the patterns and the `test` values in order just allow the detection of the string as is and dismiss special characters as just strings? Is there a function that does that appropriately?

I tried adding "\" systematically to all values in pattern. But for some reason it does not work when "N" is a pattern. But if I don't add "\" to "N" I don't have an issue. Example:

the following works:

```
patNKeep = c("*C", "*X", "#N/A N.A.", "IQ", "ERFD")
a = tibble(test = c("#N/A N.A.@sdfs", "*X@rG@RT", "*C@DFS@ER@DFG", "IQE", "SASDF"))

patNKeep %>% modify(.f = ~{
  a <<- a %>%
    filter(!str_detect(string = test, pattern = paste0("\\",.x)))
  .x
})
```

This gives an error:

```
patNKeep = c("*C", "*X", "#N/A N.A.", "IQ", "ERFD", "N")
a = tibble(test = c("#N/A N.A.@sdfs", "*X@rG@RT", "*C@DFS@ER@DFG", "IQE", "SASDF"))

patNKeep %>% modify(.f = ~{
  a <<- a %>%
    filter(!str_detect(string = test, pattern = paste0("\\",.x)))
  .x
})

Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Incorrect Unicode property. (U_REGEX_PROPERTY_SYNTAX)
```

But this works:

```
a = tibble(test = c("#N/A N.A.@sdfs", "*X@rG@RT", "*C@DFS@ER@DFG", "IQE", "SASDF"))
a %>%
  filter(!str_detect(string = test, pattern = "N"))
```

In short "N" can't to be sanitized by "\".

Comment: You are creating a wrong regex pattern with `pattern = paste0("\\",.x)`. You probably need to pass a literal pattern, try `pattern = fixed(.x)`

Comment: ah thanks. I was confused by `fixed`. What is it meant in the help file when they say "This is very fast, but not usually what you want for non-ASCII character sets." where does it fail?

Comment: They mean that if you want to match letters with diacritics and without, you should use `coll(pattern, ignore_case = FALSE, locale = "en", ...)`